# Красивое оформление таблицы в консоли С++

Tags: c++, консоль, оформление

Всем привет. Хотелось бы узнать как делать вот такую красивую таблицу в консоли : [image: оформление таблицы]

Интересует как делать такой отступ в каждой строке, штатными средствами ? Нету никаких сдвигов, все ровнехонько. Искал, не нашел  инфы такой. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Который отступ? Который в начале строки? Или разбиение на колонки?

Comment: Разбитие на колонки в том числе. Имя имеет разное кол-во символов, но дальше сдвигов нету. Как бы резерв идет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего используется два приема:
Дополнение строки лидирующими пробелами делается через что-то типа printf ("% 4d", 1);
Выравнивание в столбцы - через печать табуляции: printf ("1\t2\n123\t2\n");

Answer (score 2):

Используйте манипуляторы вывода такие, как, например, `std::setw`, `std::left`, `std::right` и другие.

Для их использования включите заголовок `<iomanip>`

Вот, например, как можно вывести заголовок

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << "ID# " << std::setw( 22 ) << std::left << "ATTRIBUTE_NAME" 
                        << std::setw( 8 ) << "FLAG"
                        << std::setw( 6 ) << "VALUE"
                        << std::setw( 6 ) << "WORST"
                        << std::setw( 7 ) << "THRESH"
                        << std::setw( 9 ) << "TYPE"
                        << std::setw( 8 ) << "UPDATE"
                        << std::setw( 12 ) << "WHEN_FAILED"
                        << "RAW_VALUE" 
                        << std::endl;
}
```

В результате запуска вы получите вывод

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME        FLAG    VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE     UPDATE  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
```

Comment: а что, ширину поля (для выравнивания по правому краю) действительно можно определить до того, как станет известна самая длинная строка, которую надо будет вывести в это поле? как же сильно я отстал от прогресса...

Comment: @alexander barakin  Таблицы проектируются до их использования в программе. Вы сначала определяете, как должна выглядеть таблица, какие будут длины полей и в соответствии с этой информацией проектируете таблицу.

Comment: жаль: я-то подумал, что прогресс ушёл вперёд.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте библиотеку [BPrinter](https://github.com/dattanchu/bprinter/wiki) (основана на Boost.Spirit, но может быть собрана и без нее). Правда она рисует границы таблицы.

```
#include <bprinter/table_printer.h>

using namespace bprinter;
TablePrinter tp(&std::cout);
tp.AddColumn("Name", 25);
tp.AddColumn("Age", 5);
tp.AddColumn("Position", 30);
tp.AddColumn("Allowance", 9);

tp.PrintHeader();
tp << "Dat Chu" << 25 << "Research Assistant" << -0.00000000001337;
tp << "John Doe" << 26 << "Too much float" << 125456789.123456789;
tp << "John Doe" << 26 << "Typical Int" << 1254;
tp << "John Doe" << 26 << "Typical float" << 1254.36;
tp << "John Doe" << 26 << "Too much negative" << -125456789.123456789;
tp << "John Doe" << 26 << "Exact size int" << 125456789;
tp << "John Doe" << 26 << "Exact size int" << -12545678;
tp << "John Doe" << 26 << "Exact size float" << -1254567.8;
tp << "John Doe" << 26 << "Negative Int" << -1254;
tp << "Jane Doe" << bprinter::endl();
tp << "Tom Doe" << 7 << "Student" << -M_PI;
tp.PrintFooter();
```

Answer (score 0):

надо знать максимальную ширину поля **до** начала вывода строк.

если ширина уже известна, то всё просто. например, функцией `printf()`:

```
### test.cpp

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int max_width, value_to_print;
    max_width = 4;
    value_to_print = 100;
    printf("%*d\ttext\n", max_width, value_to_print);
    value_to_print = 1000;
    printf("%*d\ttext\n", max_width, value_to_print);
}
```

собираем и проверяем:

```
$ make test
g++     test.cpp   -o test
$ ./test 
 100 text
1000 text
```

справку по функции `printf()` (если установлена) можно посмотреть локально командой:

```
$ man 3 printf
```

---

адаптировано из [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/757873/4827341) ответа.

Comment: В C++ можно писать decltype( auto ) func();. Хоть и громоздко, но смысл имеется. А какой в этом объявлении смысл? int void main() :)

Comment: *int void main* это опечатка при ручной правке. я исправил, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<last;i++)
    {   
    printf("\tName %5s\t",StudentList[i].name );
    printf("\tSurname %5d\t", StudentList[i].surname);
    printf("\tGroup %5s\t",StudentList[i].group);
    printf("\tMidel ball %5d\t", StudentList[i].midle);
    printf("\n\n");
    }
```

Оптимальный вариант

Answer (score 0):

самый универсальный вариант: нам нужны будут: 
`структура` в которой ты хранишь данные каждого `обьекта`. так же переменная `структура size` в которую мы будем записывать длину самого длинного поля примерно по такой логике: на старте все значения полей `0`. посредством пересчета длинны значения данных с `strlen` (если это не `string` то надо привести значение в тип `string` через `itoa` или др). ты добавляешь в список все свои обьекты и считаешь какой длины каждое поле. если длина поля больше чем то что в структуре size соответственного поля то перезаписываешь на новое значение. в конце ты будешь иметь максимальное значение каждого из полей для вывода. остается лишь запустить цикл в котором ты поставишь `size - strlen(переменная на вывод) + n`(где n это отступы между столбцами) пробелов а после и сам текст переменной на вывод. аналогично делается если отступ надо сделать сзади или разместить текст по середине.