# Табуляция в консоле

Tags: c++

Уже комп виснет от вкладок, а я никак не пойму, как сделать нормальную табуляцию в консоле.
Код для примера:

```
cout << "name" << "\t[" << "12:10:10" << "] ";
cout << "\t[" << "qwe" << "]";
cout << "\t<" << "name" << "> : " << "message" << endl;

cout << "name2" << "\t[" << "12:10:10" << "] ";
cout << "\t[" << "rqwqsvdwdfqweqr" << "]";
cout << "\t<" << "name" << "> : " << "message" << endl;
```

Ожидаемый вывод:

```
name            [12:10:10]      [qwe]                  <name> : message
name2           [12:10:10]      [rqwqsvdwdfqweqr]      <name> : message
```

Полученный вывод:

```
 name            [12:10:10]      [qwe]   <name> : message
 name2           [12:10:10]      [rqwqsvdwdfqweqr]       <name> : message
```

Уже пробовал обычные табуляторы `\t`, вертикальные табуляторы `\v` (которые так и не понял как работают), использовал `setw()`, но ничего не выходит. 
Можно, конечно, вручную считать длину имени в скобках, и в зависимости от размера давать либо `\t` либо `\t\t`, либо `\t\t\t`, но неужели нельзя всё это сделать проще?

Comment: Используйте пробелы. Или посмотрите в сторону `setw` и `resetiosflags`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/437788/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%A1

Comment: @entithat спасибо, этот вопрос мной был уже просмотрен.

Comment: Как насчет использовать `setw`?

Comment: @Harry `использовал setw(), но ничего не выходит.` покажи, пожалуйста, правильное использование setw на моём примере.

Comment: Может пригодиться - http://microsin.net/programming/arm/secrets-of-printf.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Устанавливаете выравнивание по левому краю `setiosflags(ios::left)` и указываете ширину `setw(10)`.

```
#include "iostream"
#include <iomanip> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << setiosflags(ios::left);

    cout << setw(10) << "name"; 
    cout << setw(15) << "[12:10:10]";
    cout << setw(20) << "[qwe]";
    cout << "<name> : message" << endl;

    cout << setw(10) << "name2"; 
    cout << setw(15) << "[12:10:10]";
    cout << setw(20) << "[rqwqsvdwdfqweqr]";
    cout << "<name> : message" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Прекрасно, спасибо!